# using varialbles to call marker and update options wont work

Tags: leaflet

i have to change my marker options by calling the variables assigned to them but heres the problem.

```
var CL1 = L.marker([-36.597889, -80.15625], {
     divId: 1,
     opacity: 1,
   })
   .addTo(map)


var id = 1; // this do not work 
var clickedMarker = 'CL'+id; // this do not work 
clickedMarker.setOpacity(.5); // this do not work
```

but this one work

```
CL1.setOpacity(.5); //working
```

why is that? the error I'm getting is Uncaught TypeError: clickedMarker.setOpacity is not a function

Comment: [How to ask a good question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a String with `var clickedMarker = 'CL'+id;` and with that you will not able to access the variable `CL1`. You can use a list to map the variable name with the variable self.

```
var mapping = {};

var CL1 = L.marker([-36.597889, -80.15625], {
     divId: 1,
     opacity: 1,
   })
   .addTo(map)
mapping['CL1'] = CL1;

var id = 1;
var clickedMarkerId = 'CL'+id;
var clickedMarker = mapping[clickedMarkerId]; // get the marker variable over the String 'CL1'
clickedMarker.setOpacity(.5);
```

Comment: thanks! for the explanation that worked for me.